# Can you combine a simple MYSQL Statement with a FullText Statement

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've built an internal DB / Search Engine for art creatives. I'm trying to create a search criterion where you can query one column in the database and also search several columns in the database for a phrase search using FullText Search. The example of a search query might be: **November {and} Black Friday**. November would search for creatives matching the created_for column and the black friday would search headline, subheadline and additional_text columns with a fulltext search. Any ideas of how to accomplish this would be really helpful!

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT * FROM headlines WHERE created_for = '$searchString' AND image_slug <> '') 
    (SELECT *, MATCH(headline) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS MultiScore, MATCH(subheadline, additional_text) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS MultiSecondScore 
    FROM `headlines` 
    WHERE MATCH(headline, subheadline, additional_text) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

I've tried adding a UNION statement before the second Select statement, but I get an error message saying the columns don't match. Not sure what I've got wrong here, but thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't use `(SELECT * ...)` as an expression, an expression can only return a single row with a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *, MATCH(headline) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS MultiScore, MATCH(subheadline, additional_text) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS MultiSecondScore
FROM headlines
WHERE created_for = '$searchString'
AND image_slug <> ''
AND MATCH(headline, subheadline, additional_text) AGAINST('$fullText' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

`UNION` would get results that match either of the criteria, not both of them. And when you use `UNION`, both subqueries have to return the same number of columns -- you would have to add extra columns to the first query to match the `MultiScore` and `MultiSecondScore` columns of the first query.